# Need metrics for expectations/targets

Tags: metrics

After our relaunch, we are wanting to find some standard metrics for our first year of performance. We can compare our numbers to last year and set our targets and expectations, but we would like to find an industry standard for B2B websites in Year 1 - whether as a new site or a relaunch.

Is there a way to find that information?

Comment: Are you talking about financial or eyeballs, or some other metric?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the 'standard metrics' you hope to measure, but you might like to consider these options:

1. Compare email campaign metrics with those in your industry using [MailChimp's Benchmark feature.](http://blog.mailchimp.com/compare-your-email-stats-to-industry-benchmarks/)
2. Compare approximate traffic with competitors using [Google Trends.](http://trends.google.com/websites?q=wikipedia.org%2C+imdb.com&geo=all&date=all&sort=0)

Metrics like conversion rate tend to be harder to compare because they're more closely guarded, but you can find [examples from marketing and research companies](http://www.clickz.com/clickz/column/1691779/benchmarking-average-conversion-rate) to give you an approximation if you search hard enough.